# Learning Appropriate Finger Picking Styles with Alternating Tunings

Tags: guitar, alternative-tunings, picking

I play with alternate tunings on my guitar. I've noticed several things.

1. No matter how I play it, the key of the song will be whatever my tuning is. Open C tuning leads to the song being in the key of C.
2. There are certain picking styles I've used. If I attempt to change this style, more than likely it sounds off.

What I'm trying to get at is that I'm having trouble figuring out new finger picking styles. Finger picking styles don't translate directly from standard tuning to alternate tunings well IMHO. What are some ways to learn new finger picking styles for alternate tunings and break old habits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like more than one question. Short answers:

1. Yes, that is the way with alot (clearly not all) tunings. You can fight it, but a capo or a different tuning might be a better answer for a different key.
2. Look deep into learning Travis picking, there is a whole world of serious finger picking there. There is much to learn well beyond the basic pattern that inspired dust in the wind.

Comment: More on finger picking: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1205/is-there-one-or-more-proper-finger-picking-styles-techniques